# Raphael.js: Adding a new custom element

Tags: javascript, raphael

I would like to create a custom Raphael element, with custom properties and functions. This object must also contain predefined Raphael objects. For example, I would have a node class, that would contain a circle with text and some other elements inside it. The problem is to add this new object to a set. These demands are needed because non-Raphael objects cannot be added to sets. As a result, custom objects that can contain Raphael objects cannot be used. The code would look like this:

```
var Node = function (paper) {
    // Coordinates & Dimensions
    this.x = 0,
    this.y = 0,
    this.radius = 0,
    this.draw = function () {
        this.entireSet = paper.set();
        var circle = paper.circle(this.x, this.y, this.radius);
        this.circleObj = circle;
        this.entireSet.push(circle);
        var text = paper.text(this.x, this.y, this.text);
        this.entireSet.push(text);
    }
    // other functions
}

var NodeList = function(paper){
    this.nodes = paper.set(),
    this.populateList = function(){
      // in order to add a node to the set
      // the object must be of type Raphael object
      // otherwise the set will have no elements
      this.nodes.push(// new node)
    }
    this.nextNode = function(){
        // ...
    }
    this.previousNode = function(){
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Raphael.fn. It is explained how to add custom functions which can create complex objects as result of the function like .arrow() or whatever you want.

Comment: As far as I know, Raphael.fn does not create a Raphael object. Thus, the created objects cannot be added to a Raphael set. My class looks like this:

var Node = function () {
    // Coordinates & Dimensions
    this.x = 0,
    this.y = 0,
    this.radius = 0,
    this.stroke = 1,
    //...
    return this;
    }

Comment: It is the function that you attach to .fn who creates it. If you want to create a circle with a text inside (if I've understand your question) I would do it this way, like in this example https://gist.github.com/1043360. If your object is a path then you can add it to a set. Even more, you can create text and circles separately to put them into the set. You can also put your custom attributes to it.

Comment: My problem is that I need to access the properties from the created object(x, y, radius , stroke from the example below). That's why I would need a custom object that can be seen as a Raphael object. In the example you gave the function returns predefined Raphael objects and the classes I have are more complex and cannot use only Raphael elements. I also have custom functions for the objects that I create (like previous and next), so I don't really know if adding custom attributes to predefined objects will work for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can only add Raphael object (rect,circle, eclipse,text) to paper.set(), *not self defined object*( with Raphael.fn) . Instead use normal array definition of javascript [].
As fas as i understand nodeList is a simple list but with more options like nextnode , previous nodes.

Take a look at this demo, i changed abit José Manuel Cabrera's codes: http://jsfiddle.net/Tomen/JNPYN/1/

```
Raphael.fn.node = function(x, y, radius, txt) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.radius = radius;
    this.txt = txt;
    this.circleObj = paper.circle(this.x, this.y, radius), this.textObj = paper.text(this.x, this.y, this.txt);
    this.entireSet = paper.set(this.circleObj, this.textObj);
    return this
}
Raphael.fn.nodeList = function() {
    this.nodes = [];
    this.push = function(p) {
        return this.nodes.push(p);
    };

    //  this.nextNode = function(){
    // ... manipulate this.nodes here
    // }
    //  this.previousNode = function(){
    // ...
    //  }
    return this
}
var ca = paper.node(250, 150, 50.0, "hola");
var list = paper.nodeList();
list.push(ca);
```

Comment: You're welcome hehe. I was thinking the same as you: why not to store the the nodes in a normal array. But then, I think the easier way is to use var Node = function ... And that's all I think :)

Comment: Forget the var Node = ... hehe it's ok adding it to the .fn

Comment: Thanks to your codes Jose , i'm new to Raphael. I just come by while waiting for answers of my other question, but no one answered so far,haha.

Answer (score 2):

Some examples may fall down if there is no global 'paper'
The context of Raphael.fn.yrMethod will be the instance (paper)
This example creates a raphael object which wraps a g element, which is for some reason not currently supported:

```
    (function(R){

        function g(_paper){

            var _canvas = _paper.canvas,
                _node = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "g");

            _canvas.appendChild(_node);

            this.add = function(rElement){
                _node.appendChild(rElement.node);
            }

            this.remove = function(rElement){
                _canvas.appendChild(rElement.node);
            }

            this.transform = function(tString){
                _node.setAttribute('transform', tString);
            }

        }

        R.fn.g = function(){
            return new g(this);
        }

    })(Raphael);
```

Answer (score 1):

this code allow you to create a node with a text (it returns a set) and you can manipulate it as a Raphael object (put the method after loading the dom):

```
    function loadShape(){
    Raphael.fn.node = function(x, y, radius, txt){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.radius = radius;
        this.txt = txt;

        this.drawCircle = function () {
            return paper.circle(this.x, this.y, radius);
        };
        this.drawText = function () {
            return paper.text(this.x, this.y, this.txt);
        };

        this.draw = function(){
            var group = paper.set();
            var circulo = paper.circle(this.x, this.y, radius);
            var texto = paper.text(this.x, this.y, this.txt);
            group.push(circulo);
            group.push(texto);
            return group;
        }
        this.init = function(ox, oy, r, t){
            this.x = ox;
            this.y = oy;
            this.radius = r;
            this.txt = t;
        };
        // etc…
        return this;
    };
    var paper = new Raphael(document.getElementById("wrapper"), "100%", "100%");

    //var nodo = paper.node();
    //nodo.init(50, 50, 2.0, "soy un nodo");
    var nodo = paper.node(250, 150, 50.0, "hola");
    nodo.draw();
    //circ.attr({"propiedad":"hola"});
    //alert(circ.attr("propiedad"));
}
```

Tell me if this was useful to you!

Comment: init method is like a set() but if you want to change the settings for your node, you have to remove the previous set and redraw it! You can also define internal functions that can do this ;)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have edited my question with more explanations. I have had a similar implementation to the one you suggested. Unfortunately, I can't use it, because I need to add the node to a Raphael set. I cannot add only the set returned by the draw method, because I need the properties declared in the node object.

Comment: And why not using a simple array to store your nodes and replacing the Raphael.fn.node by var Node = as you wrote on your question?